# add class to li on hover but remove from all others

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, mouseenter

I need to add a class to an `li` on hover but remove the same class from all other `li`s in the list (this is for a nav).

The code I have so far is:

```
jQuery(".navcontent").on('mouseenter', 'li', function() {
    if (jQuery('.childmenu', this)) {
        jQuery('.childmenu', this).addClass("child-active");
    } else {
        jQuery('.navcontent li .childmenu').removeClass("child-active");
    }
});
```

I can't quite work out what I need to do...

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Kindly post your HTML structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have alternative ways to do that:

1. first remove class of all the elements and add one you want:

```
    jQuery(".navcontent li").on('mouseenter', function() {
        jQuery('.childmenu').removeClass("child-active");
        jQuery('.childmenu', this).addClass("child-active");
    });
```

2. if they are siblings, you can use `siblings`:

```
    jQuery(".navcontent li").on('mouseenter', function() {
        jQuery('.childmenu', this).addClass("child-active")
          .siblings('.childmenu').removeClass("child-active");
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check the code below

```js
jQuery(".navcontent li").on('mouseenter', function(event) {
  jQuery('.navcontent li').removeClass("child-active");
  jQuery(this).addClass("child-active");

});
```

```css
.child-active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navcontent">
  <li>Links</li>
  <li>Links</li>
  <li>Links</li>
  <li>Links</li>
  <li>Links</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(".navcontent li").on('mouseenter', function(event) {
    jQuery('.navcontent li .childmenu').removeClass("child-active");
    jQuery(event.target).addClass("child-active");

});
```

Comment: It's more idiomatic to use `jQuery(this)` rather than `jQuery(event.target)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(".navcontent li").on('mouseover', function() {
    jQuery(".navcontent li .childmenu").removeClass('child-active');
    jQuery(this).addClass('child-active');
});
```

Use above code

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(".navcontent li").on('mouseenter', function() {
    jQuery(".navcontent li").removeClass("child-active");
    jQuery(this).addClass("child-active");
});
```